# Sharepoint 2010 Install on VM - Is it possible to isolate it from rest of the corporate network while giving connectivity to some devs?

Tags: development, active-directory, virtual-machine, networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SharePoint 2010 and Active Directory](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16451/sharepoint-2010-and-active-directory)

I have a corporate network. The system admin has created a VMware VM for us with Windows Server 2008 R2 on which to install Sharepoint Server 2010. The VM has no network connectivity. We connect to the VM using Vmware Vsphere client. This was done because we were not sure if the sharepoint server 2010 install would mess in any way with AD.

However, having done that, now the issue is how to use it as a server and connect to the server from VS on our dev machines, as well as sharepoint designer?? Can someone please shed some light and provide alternate ways of connecting the VM to the network and installing sharepoint 2010 without it interfering with the AD Schema?

Is it possible to create a virtual network between the dev machines and this VM, keeping the VM isolated from the rest of the corporate network (or any other suggestions)?

The system admin is very reluctant to bring the VM over to the domain and provide it with network connectivity. Without network connectivity, it is pretty much useless to have this VM and server on it in the first place when no one can connect to it.

And does sharepoint 2010 install mess with ad schema in any way?

Comment: YOUR CAPS LOCK KEY IS BROKEN.

Comment: I fixed your caps key and sticking question mark key ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick devop hack to your complex scenario:

Have the developers connect to a remote session on the VM based on logon accounts from the VMs isolated Active Directory. Get all the dev tools on the VM and they should be good. To avoid interruptions from application pool resets have them work on different Web Applications.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I want to avoid that route. I still want out already 'DEVED UP' (for lack of a better phrase :)) to be used to connect to the server. Is there a solution on the network side for this? For example, setting up a VPN for example?
If yes, I can talk to my system admin about that route. Thanks again for your suggestion and feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Installing SharePoint doesn't do anything to your Active Directory schema.

There is also no reason to not have the VM on the network - we have multiple SharePoint development VMs that are on our domain.  We remote into them (and restrict permission to each individual VM) in order to do development.

Having the VM on the domain is very helpful. No need to manage different credentials, and connecting to TFS and other network resources is easy.

I definitely don't recommend that developers share a single VM ... Set up a VM for each developer and save yourself the headaches.

Answer (score 1):

all sharepoint does is read AD, I'm also the system admin who installed sharepoint 2010 also on a VM for the front end server and had it create its database's on an existing MSSQL 2005 DB server.  No Problems, works great actually its nice to have a intranet to ties in with AD so very well.